# How is ammonia used in production or processing of steel?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metallurgy

There are some large tanks of ammonia in nearby iron works.

[image]

I wonder, what do they need it for? What is the application of ammonia in steel industry - what processes of making or processing steel require this much ammonia?

Comment: Ammonia is used for production of Nitrogen and Hydrogen using Ammonia Cracking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely, for nitriding http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitriding . Essentially, ammonia is used as nitrogen donor. Nitrogen atoms diffuse into steel, producing hardened, corrosion-resistant surface layer.

Comment: Indeed - N2 will not nitride steel in a thermal process.  NH3 breaks up much more easily, so that is used.